# Cannot find name module

Tags: angular

Cannot find
name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

Comment: Please add more information to your question. In order to help you we need your code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
npm i @types/node --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, UserService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})

export class RegisterComponent {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    register() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.userService.create(this.model)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.alertService.success('Registration successful', true);
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
The above is my code where it is showing "Cannot find name module" error...
```